# Count number of character before 2 @

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a problem with my query. I need to create a query to count all characters except of all characters between symbol @. For example I have :

```
@CN@Test
@DATE@hjkjhkjh@DATE@hjkh@SC@hkhkjhkjhkjhkj@SC@
```

I can have multiple @ into an expression

I want to get value 4 not 8, so without @CN@.
I tried :

```
SELECT e.id as event_id,length(em.value) as num_count
FROM event_mt em
INNER JOIN event e ON e.id = em.id_event
WHERE e.del_date IS NULL 
AND em.value not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

The regex is not correct.
Help me please.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm using SQL Server

Comment: The regex should be something like this: `^(@*@)`

Comment: can there be more than 2 @ - if yes then show input and respective desired-output

Comment: @CN@ Test @DATE_@ and @DATE_F@ where @SC@ @PX_L@

Comment: So what would be the value for the second example?

Comment: The  value whoud be 12

Comment: ??? Where does 12 come from? I get the first example because "test" is 4 characters. 12 makes no sense based on the values posted for the second one. Help us understand what you are trying to do and we can help. Otherwise there is nothing anybody can do.

Comment: Keep in mind that SQL Server does not support regexes out of the box. You have to implement them. That said, I would recommend doing a regex replace (once you implement that function) replacing `@[^@]*@` with the empty string, then getting the length of whatever is left over.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(30)='@CN@Test'

SELECT len(LEFT(@str, Charindex('@', @str)-1) +
       + Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(@str), Charindex('@', Reverse(@str))-1)))
```

Comment: @HareaCostea . . . Then edit your question and provide more examples with the lengths that you want.

Comment: @HareaCostea - what is the expected output for this one `@DATE@hjkjhkjh@DATE@hjkh@SC@hkhkjhkjhkjhkj@SC@`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it with replaces nested : 
      SELECT e.id as event_id,em.id,
     (LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(em.value, 'dfd',   ''),'ghgfh',''),'wer',''),'65756',''))) as message_count
FROM event